# Unable to see table in DataGridView in WinForms

Tags: c#, ado

Please help me to find the solution.

I am unable to get data displayed in the datagridview control of WinForms.
I tried both Connected & Disconnected Architecture.But still cannot see the data.

Following is my code 1 :

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from employ", con);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds);
 bindingSource1.DataSource = ds;
 dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

& this is my code 2 :

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from employ", con);
 using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
 {
     BindingSource b1 = new BindingSource();
     b1.DataSource = dr;
     dataGridView1.DataSource = b1;
 }
```

Where am I wrong?I can see the table populated while debugging but not in the UI.

Comment: Add a C# tag to get more views

Answer (score 0):

Need to add

```
 dataGridView1.Databind()
```

after setting the datasource

Comment: There is no Databind() method for DataGridView.

Comment: oh sorry thinking webforms